# Sum excel rows based on a cell value

Tags: php, html, excel, import, export

I currently have a spreadsheet which has between 10-12 columns. I want to sum the number of rows, in HTML. However, I want this sum to be dependent on a specific column value.

Column 9, we'll say, is a pull down with 6 different possible choices. So, I want to sum "CHOICE 1" and present the number in a 'div' section.

Note: I am using php's to create this website.

Example:

Possible values: "A,B,C,D,E,F,G"

$SUM_A=SUM(rows with A value)
echo "These are the number of rows with A" . $SUM_A .

I haven't found much online that helped me, maybe I'm wording my search wrong.. Any help is greatly appreciated!

TIA!

Comment: Is this a real Excel file, in which case Excel has functions that can be used for precisely this purpose such as [SUMIF()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sumif-function-HP010062465.aspx)

Comment: Never knew about SUMIF(). Thanks, @MarkBaker! Then I can just call the value of the individual cell that sums

Comment: Store the formula in any appropriate cell, then you can just get the calculated value from that cell

Comment: This post may help you - http://evolt.org/node/26896/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it well you have a Excel tool that you want to export in HTML for your website?

If that's the case, you might be interested in Appizy (http://appizy.com). This website converts an Excel spreadsheet into dynamic webapplication. You can then download the HTML, CSS, Javascript code and paste it into your website.

Hope that helps. Nicolas